# React - two external packages destroy animations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, package

I installed two packages:

- react-custom-roulette
- react-dice-roll

They work fine if it is only one of them, but if I render `<Wheel>` from react-custom-roulette, animation of `<Dice>` from react-dice-roll is broken. It only spins around.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-morning-wb4hgz?file=/src/App.tsx

You can just delete `<Wheel>` component from that code and refresh the page and everything works as it should work.

Why something like this happening? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why something like this happening?

CSS animations must be defined with a global name, and unfortunately the 2 mentioned libraries use the same `spin` name, so the last one overwrites the other, and interferes with the other library animation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes#resolving_duplicates

> If multiple keyframe sets exist for a given name, the last one encountered by the parser is used.

- [react-dice-roll/src/styles.scss](https://github.com/avaneeshtripathi/react-dice-roll/blob/394384937edcfdeac67aa0430af805bfaa80814e/src/styles.scss#L77) `@keyframes spin`
- [react-custom-roulette/src/components/Wheel/styles.js](https://github.com/effectussoftware/react-custom-roulette/blob/bd36a2be636eb2fbedbfce8ce791118feeed965b/src/components/Wheel/styles.js#L42) `@keyframes spin`

---

> How can I fix that?

Both libraries directly embed their styles, so it is not straightforward to swap one style with a fixed version.

However, react-dice-roll uses a "non-dynamically scoped" stylesheet (i.e. non CSS-in-JS-based), so it is still quite simple to overwrite the style bits that conflict:

```css
/* In your app stylesheet (make sure to import it AFTER react-dice-roll) */

/* Overwrite the styles that contain the animation name */
._space3d.rolling ._3dbox {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    animation: spin2 2s infinite linear;
}

/* Copy the animation with a new unique name */
@keyframes spin2 {
    0% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg); }
    16% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(180deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg); }
    33% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(180deg); }
    50% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(360deg); }
    66% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(180deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(270deg); }
    83% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(270deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg); }
    100% { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(360deg); }
}
```

Fixed example: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-danilo-o6ibvo?file=/src/styles.css